# Error: (E112) get interface failed: port is not bound - SystemC

Tags: c++, systemc

My goal is to create an ALU that adds and subtracts with a barrelshifter

**alu.h**

```
#include "systemc.h"       

SC_MODULE(alu){
sc_in<bool> op;
sc_in<sc_int<8> > a;
sc_inout<sc_int<8> > b;
sc_out<sc_int<8> > output;

void alu_method();  

SC_CTOR(alu) {
    SC_METHOD(alu_method);
    dont_initialize();
    sensitive << a,b,op;
    }
};
```

**alu.cpp**

```
#include "alu.h"

void ALU::alu_method(){
if (op.read() == 0){
    //substract
    out.write(in.read() - in_bs.read());
}
else{
    //add
    out.write(in.read() + in_bs.read());
    }
}
```

**barrelshift.h**

```
    #include <systemc.h>       
    void make_barrel();

    SC_MODULE(barrel_shift) {
    sc_in<bool> clk;
    sc_in<bool> enable;
    sc_in<bool> left_right;
    sc_in<sc_uint<3> > shift_amt;
    sc_in<sc_int<8> > din;
    sc_inout<sc_int<8> > dout;

void barrel_method();   

    SC_CTOR(barrel_shift) {

    SC_METHOD(barrel_method);
dont_initialize();
    sensitive << clk.pos(); //edge sensitive
    }

};
```

**barrelshift.cpp**

```
    #include "barrelshift.h"

    void barrel_shift :: barrel_method(){

if(enable.read() == 1){
    if(left_right.read() == 0){ //shift left
                dout.write(din.read() << shift_amt.read()); 

    }else if(left_right.read() == 1){ // right shift
                dout.write(din.read() >> shift_amt.read());
    }
}
else 
        cout << "Not enabled "<<endl;
        dout <= din;    
}
```

**sc_main.cpp**

```
    #include <systemc.h>
    #include "alu.h"
    #include "barrelshift.h"

    int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]){
sc_trace_file *tf; 

//Signals
sc_signal <bool> enable, op, l_r;
sc_signal <sc_int<8> > a, output,b, bin;
sc_signal < sc_uint<3> > shift_amt;

//Clock
sc_clock clk("clk",10,SC_PS,0.5);

alu myALU("myALU");
barrel_shift myShifter("myShifter");

myALU.a(a);
myALU.b(b);
myALU.output(output);
myALU.op(op);

myShifter.clk(clk);
myShifter.din(bin);
myShifter.enable(enable);
myShifter.left_right(l_r);
myShifter.shift_amt(shift_amt);
myShifter.dout(b);

tf = sc_create_vcd_trace_file("trace_file");
sc_trace(tf, clk, "clk");
sc_trace(tf, a, "a");
sc_trace(tf, bin, "BarrelShifter In");
sc_trace(tf, op, "op");
sc_trace(tf, shift_amt, "shift_amt");
sc_trace(tf, l_r, "left_right");
sc_trace(tf, enable, "enable");
sc_trace(tf, b, "b");
sc_trace(tf, output, "output");



sc_close_vcd_trace_file(tf);

cout << "The result from the ALU is: " << output.read();
}
```

There are no errors when I build it. But whenever I try to execute it, I get the following error:

> Error: (E112) get interface failed: port is not bound: port 'myALU.port_0' (sc_in)
>   In file: sc_port.cpp:231

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message

```
Error: (E112) get interface failed: port is not bound: port 'myALU.port_0' (sc_in)
```

means that the port `myALU.port_0` is not bound to a signal. But which port in the `alu` module corresponds to `port_0`?

It is good practice to name all ports and signals -- regardless of the type of hardware description language you are using -- to make errors like this easier to diagnose.

Name the ports in the `alu` constructor:

```cpp
SC_CTOR(alu) :
    op("op"),
    a("a"),
    b("b"),
    output("output")
{
    // ...
```

I couldn't reproduce the error you were seeing. I saw this error (after providing names for all ports and signals):

```
Error: (E115) sc_signal<T> cannot have more than one driver:
 signal `signal_5' (sc_signal)
 first driver `myShifter.dout'  (sc_inout)
 second driver `myALU.b' (sc_inout)
```

I noticed some other problems in your code:

- Your code doesn't compile because the wrong variable names are used in `alu_method()`.
- `sc_start()` is not called in `sc_main()`.
- There is an invalid `sensitive` call in `alu()` -- should be `sensitive << a << b << op;`

Comment: Any idea how to name a port array (specifically, all array members)? `op[0]("op_0")` does not seem to work.

Comment: Found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35425052/274579. A comment suggests that there's no good solution for this in SC.

Comment: `sc_core::sc_vector<sc_in<bool> > op` works well for that. Initialize it with `op("op", 3")` and the three elements get the names `op_0`, `op_1`, and `op_2`.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Unfortunately, my ports are simple arrays, not vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the sensitivity list for `alu`.  It should have been:

```
sensitive << a << b << op;
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted correctly by @DarrylLawson, this error message indicates that the the port `myALU.port_0` is not bound to a signal (and you would get a clearer name if you had given the port a name in the constructor).

An important nuance imho is that it means the port is not bound to a signal *at the time the error is given*.  You may have code that binds it, but this is only executed at some point during elaboration.  If you try to use the port before that (e.g. inside the constructor of your  module), you can still get this error message.  In that case the error would occur at time 0.